# Running "regedit "filename" to import .reg file from powershell

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit, windows-registry

I'm trying to import a registry file by running regedit. The problem is that the powershell script has to run from a 32 bit executable, but I want to run the 64 bit regedit. Any ideas on how I can force the use of the 64 bit regedit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you explicitly call the executable in the windows directory, you will get the system native version.  If you do not specify an absolute path, you will get the WOW64 version.

This will always open 32 bit:

```
Start-Process regedit
```

This will open the 64 bit version when on x64, or the 32 bit version when running on a 32 bit machine:

```
Start-Process "$env:windir\regedit.exe"
```

If you only want your script to execute on 64 bit, you can detect your running architecture, by checking `$env:Processor_Architecture` and error out when it doesn't meet your requirements.

Note: This works because 'regedit.exe' is stored in your Windows directory.  If you want to access a 64-bit application from a 32-bit context, and the application happens to be in System32 instead, you can use `$env:windir\sysnative\<APPLICATION>`.  `$env:windir\sysnative` gives you the 64-bit `System32` instead of the redirect to `SysWOW64`.

Comment: I tried to use Start-Process with "$env:windir\regedit.exe" to import a file that has `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TESTING` as a key, but it still wrote it under the WOW6432Node.

Comment: I checked this a bit further and confirmed that if I run: Start-Process "$env:windir\regedit.exe" from `Power GUI Script Editor (x86)` it still launches the 32 version of regedit.

Comment: I was unable to duplicate the issue you describe while using the PowerShell ISE (x86).  Perhaps there are other platform considerations that I am unaware of.  Tested on W7 x64 and W2K8R2 x64.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `reg import` under `sysnative`:

```
Start-Process $env:windir\sysnative\reg.exe import <.REG_FILE>
```

`$env:windir\sysnative` gives you the 64-bit `System32` instead of the 32-bit context redirect to `SysWOW64`.